# Pip freeze listing out global packages in conda env

Tags: python, pip, conda, freeze

I am using conda as my environment and created a new environment for a project. After installing packages in that env using pip I used `pip freeze -r requirements.txt` to save my package dependencies in requirements.txt file, but all package that is installed globally is being added to the requirements file. How can track packages installed in the env only?

Here is the step I followed:

```
1. conda create -n tf_env 
2. conda activate tf_env
3. pip install pandas
```

Then when I do `pip freeze -l`, I get the following output:

```
adal==1.2.2
affine==2.3.1
aiohttp==3.6.2
aiohttp-retry==2.4.6
alabaster==0.7.12
alembic==1.7.7
altair==4.2.0
aniso8601==9.0.1
appdirs==1.4.4
applicationinsights==0.11.9
apturl==0.5.2
argcomplete==1.8.1
argon2-cffi==21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
asn1crypto==1.4.0
asttokens==2.0.5
async-timeout==3.0.1
asyncssh==2.10.1
atpublic==3.0.1
attrs==19.3.0
audioread==2.1.9
avro==1.11.0
azure==4.0.0
azure-ai-textanalytics==1.0.0b1
azure-appconfiguration==1.0.0
azure-applicationinsights==0.1.0
....
```

and many more packages that are installed globally. Thought I should only get pandas and related dependencies.

Comment: If you have activate your enviroment pip freeze should work

Comment: I have activated my environment.

Comment: `pip freeze -l`?

Comment: Same output when using pip freeze -l

Comment: Please add more info to question. For instance, show exactly the `pip install` command used; show how you activate the environment; show how you verify that `pip` is from the environment; show a representative subset of the `pip freeze` output; point out which packages you don't want showing up (how do you know they are global?); add any attempted workarounds that don't work to the question (e.g., `pip freeze -l`).

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to improve my question.